Using TextToSpeech from another class file doesn't work in Kotlin
I am trying to use TextToSpeech in an Activity.
And I also want to move this to a seperate class file called Helper, and load it from there.
So I created the code below.
// Helper.kt
class Helper {
    private var tts: TextToSpeech? = null

    fun initTextToSpeech(context: Context) {
        // 롤리팝(API 21, Android 5.0)이상에서만 지원됨
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "지원하지 않는 SDK 버전입니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        tts = TextToSpeech(context) {
            if (it == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                val result = tts?.setLanguage(Locale.KOREAN)
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "지원하지 않는 언어입니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//                    return@TextToSpeech
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "TTS 설정 성공", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "TTS 설정 실패", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    fun ttsSpeak(str: String) {
        tts?.speak(str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")
    }
}


I called it like this in the activity as below, but it didn't work.
There is no error, but it does not work either.
class QuizQuestionsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var btnAudio: ImageButton? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions)

        Helper().initTextToSpeech(this)

        btnAudio = findViewById(R.id.btn_audio)
        btnAudio?.setOnClickListener(this)

    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {

        // 클릭된 view 요소에 따라 메서드 실행
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.btn_audio -> {
                val question = mQuestionList?.get(mCurrentPosition - 1)
                question?.let { Helper().ttsSpeak(question.question) }
            }
        }
    }
}

It works well if I include it in the Activity itself as below.
(* Please note that some parts that are not directly related have been omitted.)
// QuizQuestionsActivity.kt

class QuizQuestionsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
   
   private var btnAudio: ImageButton? = null
   var tts: TextToSpeech? = null

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions)

        initTextToSpeech()

        btnAudio = findViewById(R.id.btn_audio)
        btnAudio?.setOnClickListener(this)  
   }

   fun initTextToSpeech() {
        // 롤리팝(API 21, Android 5.0)이상에서만 지원됨
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "지원하지 않는 SDK 버전입니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        tts = TextToSpeech(this) {
            if (it == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                val result = tts?.setLanguage(Locale.KOREAN)
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "지원하지 않는 언어입니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//                    return@TextToSpeech
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "TTS 설정 성공", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "TTS 설정 실패", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    fun ttsSpeak(str: String) {
        tts?.speak(str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, "")
    }

     override fun onClick(view: View?) {

        // 클릭된 view 요소에 따라 메서드 실행
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.btn_audio -> {
                val question = mQuestionList?.get(mCurrentPosition - 1)
                question?.let { ttsSpeak(question.question) }
            }
        }
    }
}


I'm still new to Kotlin, so I don't know the cause.
Why the first one doesn't work and how can I make it work?
I don't understand because actually there are other methods in the Helper class and they works fine in the activity, except for the TextToSpeech one.

In my app TextToSpeech is declared in the activity, passed to the gamehelper object (for a welcome phrase) and stopped in the activity
// TTS
var tTS1: TextToSpeech? = null
var toSpeak: String? = null
    // TTS
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        tTS1 = TextToSpeech(context) { status ->
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                welcomeSpeech(context, realm, sharedLastPlayer!!, tTS1!!)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
/**
 * destroy SpeechRecognizer, TTS shutdown
 *
 * @see android.app.Activity.onDestroy
 */
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    destroyRecognizer()
    // TTS
    if (tTS1 != null) {
        tTS1!!.stop()
        tTS1!!.shutdown()
    }
}

gamehelper object
/**
 * welcome speech
 *
 * @param context context
 * @param realm realm
 * @param sharedLastPlayer string
 * @see Phrases
 */
fun welcomeSpeech(context: Context,
                  realm: Realm,
                  sharedLastPlayer: String,
                  tTS1: TextToSpeech,
                  ) {
    // TTS
    val phraseToSearch1 = realm.where(Phrases::class.java)
        .equalTo(context.getString(R.string.tipo), context.getString(R.string.welcome_phrase_first_part))
        .findFirst()
    val phraseToSearch2 = realm.where(Phrases::class.java)
        .equalTo(context.getString(R.string.tipo), context.getString(R.string.welcome_phrase_second_part))
        .findFirst()
    if (phraseToSearch1 != null && phraseToSearch2 != null) {
        val toSpeak = (phraseToSearch1.descrizione + " " + sharedLastPlayer
                + " " + phraseToSearch2.descrizione)
        tTS1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "prova tts")
    }
}


Um.. could you explain more? Since your structures are different with mine, I don't know how to apply into my code.

I apologize to the kind Jiwon, but in my haste I didn't copy a piece of activity; I just updated it

Thank you! I got it from what you showed me, and I made it. :D
